# Java executable .jar file not working properly after compiling in NETBeans IDE

Tags: java, sql

I am exporting a .jar file from a GUI built in Netbeans IDE. It works fine within Netbeans but once it is exported, some logic in the code does not execute properly.

I have tried debugging by running test cases displaying which items are passing through the if clauses. It seems to work well in IDE but not when it is run through .jar file.

```
for(Chamber chamber: chs)
        {
            if(!scheduledTools.containsKey(chamber))//unscheduled chambers
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, chamber.getName()+": is unscheduled");
                    model.addElement(chamber.getName());
                }
            else//scheduled
            {
                if((scheduledTools.get(chamber).size()/range) > .25)
                {
                    System.out.println("Range: " +range+" Scheduled: " +scheduledTools.get(chamber).size());
                    System.out.println("Cannot use this chambers:" +chamber.getName());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, chamber.getName()+": Cannot use this chamber");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Scheduled but can use"+chamber.getName());

                    altModel.addElement(chamber.getName());

                }
            }
        }

        alternateChambers.setModel(altModel);alternateChambers.setSelectedIndex(0);
        suggestedChambers.setModel(model);suggestedChambers.setSelectedIndex(0);

        if(altModel.size()>1){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Scheduled but can use these chambers:"+altModel);}
```

After making the necessary queries in seekDates method below:

```
private void seekDates(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {

        ArrayList<String> entries;

        //get how many dates we have so we can update progressbar
            int results = 0;

            setProgress(results);

            if(rs.last()){results=rs.getRow();rs.beforeFirst();}

        // processing returned data and printing into console
            while(rs.next()) {

                String scheduledChamber =  rs.getString(2);

                for(Chamber chamber : chambers){
                    //if the scheduled tool is a thermal chamber
                    //chambers get listed so far

                    if(!scheduledChamber.trim().toLowerCase().contains(chamber.getName().toLowerCase()))
                    {}//print chambers im not saving
                    else{
                        if(scheduledTools.containsKey(chamber))
                        {
                            //if key already used, just grab the list and add date
                            entries = scheduledTools.get(chamber);
                            entries.add(rs.getString(1).split(" ")[0]);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if chamber hasnt been saved, add chamber and date
                            entries = new ArrayList<String>();
                            entries.add(rs.getString(1).split(" ")[0]);
                            scheduledTools.put(chamber, entries);

                        }

                    //System.out.println("Just saved this chamber:" +scheduledChamber+" with this date:" +scheduledTools.get(chamber));
                    }
                    ;

                }

                publish(rs.getRow());
                Thread.yield();

                setProgress(100*(rs.getRow()/results));
        }
    }
```

The GUI should display the chambers found in the queries in one text field while displaying the rest of the chambers in another text field.

When I run this in the IDE. I get the correct outcome but once I compile using the package-for-store option in the build.xml file, the outcome then just lists all of the chambers in one text field.

In the .jar file, it seems that all of the chambers only satisfy the first if clause and none of the others.

Comment: how are you running? use zip to see contents of jar. are your dependencies there? stacktrace?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the Chamber class.